# Cannot execute files on another partition

Tags: linux, filesystems, permissions, ntfs

On my system I have three partitions: one is shared between W7 and Linux Mint (NTFS), and the other two are OS-specific.

In my home directory I have created a symbolic link to another directory on the shared partition.

I have a simple `.cpp` file there which I compiled via `g++ name.cpp`. Usually, this would also make the file executable, but this time I had to manually `chmod 755` it.

Strangely, this didn't work either, the console said it did not have the required permission. So I executed `sudo chmod 755 a.out`. This asked me for my password, and reported no errors. However, it had no effect. `a.out` was not executable. I've noticed some other strange behaviors in symlink directories too.

Whats going on and how can I fix it?

**Edit:** 
My mount options:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=7c50dab1-730b-4d3c-a944-51da19c8e2c6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=12e39b76-7f19-4c6d-a724-81ea29211db1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sda5 /media/yannbane/Shared ntfs defaults,fmask=117,dmask=007,gid=46 0 0
```

Comment: Linux and NTFS often seem to not play well together, unfortunately.

Comment: Could you please share the mount options? You either provide them as your `mount` command options or in your `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @Leonid, here, see the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, there is `fmask` option and it's set to `117`. That effectively disables the exec permissions for anyone. If you don't want any restrictions, you may set it to `0` and remount. But please be aware: any restriction here was added to avoid problems and pitfalls.

Comment: I remember there being a problem with *every* file being executable... Will this happen? I'll try it later I'm in a middle of something now, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it will: all the files will be treated as executable. Basically, it does not want to distinguish between different types.